# JSONException occurred during parsing

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I have follow map:

```
{
errors=[], 
warnings=[], 
items=[{
    itemKey=3806, 
    errors=[], 
    warnings=[<span style="color: #000;">Der Titel ist im Unternehmen bereits vorhanden.</span>]
}], 
surchargeItems=[{
    parentConfigurationKey=3806, 
    surchargeDescription=Logistikkosten, 
    surchargePrice=1.00, 
    surchargeCurrencyId=EUR}]
}
```

and during calling method parse of **grails.converters.JSON** class i have follow exception:

org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or ']' at character 79 of {errors=[], warnings=[], items=[{itemKey=3806, errors=[], warnings=[

How can i parse the html which json contains? Thx!

Comment: that's not json. it's not even CLOSE to being valid json. it's not even valid javascript

Comment: It sounds like it is butchered around your warnings section.

Comment: Here, try this: http://jsonlint.com/.   If it passes there, then I'll bet the converter will parse it